# Unable to insert this string into a column. Only part of the string Is inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-injection, code-injection

I am using SQL Server 2008. And I am trying to insert a string into a table but only part of the string is inserted. I have checked whether it is a SQL injection risk. How to solve or avoid this problem?

```
insert into tble (col1, col2, col3) 
values (23, 34, "out of 8 works, 5 works are completed");
```

Only `Out of 8 Works` is inserted, `, 5 works are completed` was skipped

Comment: Replace your double quotes with single. 
insert into tble (col1,col2,col3) values (23,34,'out of 8 works, 5 works are completed');

Comment: `declare @temp table
(val nvarchar(max))

insert into @temp (val) values ('out of 8 works, 5 works are completed');`

Comment: What is the datatype of col3? `varchar(15)` would be my guess. If so, make it `varchar(100)`Looks like string truncation to me.

Comment: Well, what **datatype** is your column `col3` ? And most interestingly: **HOW LONG** is that string column defined?? Does it possibly only allow **15 characters** ? (`varchar(15)` or `nvarchar(15)`) - that would explain it .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double quotes will only work if QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS is turned off, if you are worried about SQL injection then don't pass a string on the INSERT - parameterise it from the application. The string could be truncated because the col3 is not defined long enough - check that also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
insert into table(col1,col2,col3) values (23,34,'out of 8 works, 5 works are completed');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the size of col3 in your table (based on your string size).
You can change it by using the following query:

alter table tble

alter column col3 nvarchar(100) [null | not null]

Comment: No Modify in Sql Server.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190273.aspx                                                                                 ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype...